# Need help testing my smart contract

Tags: testing, erc-1155, typescript

I am currently in the process of testing my solidity smart contract using hardhat and am a bit confused on how I should do it. This is the very first time I am testing a smart contract so I am bit rusty and its a bit confusing to me. I am using typescript. Here is my smart contract and below I pasted the test I have so far. It is a simple erc1155 smart contract that mints tokens when the the constructor is called.

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    // OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.9.0) (token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol)


    pragma solidity 0.8.19;


    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155Receiver.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Receiver.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155URIStorage.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol";



    contract SpiderVerse is IERC1155, ERC1155{

      //Defining the variables that will be used in this contract along with their ids.
      uint public constant MILES_MORALES = 0;
      uint public constant GWEN_STACY = 1;
      uint public constant PETER_B_PARKER =2;
      uint public constant MIGUEL_O_HARA = 3;
      uint public constant HOBBIE_BROWN = 4;
      uint public constant JESSICA_DREW = 5;
      uint public constant PAVITIR_PRABHAKAR = 6;
      uint public constant PENI_PARKER = 7;
      uint public constant PETER_NOIR_PARKER = 8;
      uint public constant PETER_PORKER = 9;
      uint public constant SPIDEY_TOKENS = 10;

       bytes public constant tokenSymbol = "SDT" ;

     //constructor will mint all NFTS and Fungible Spidey Tokens at once.
      constructor () ERC1155("https://app.pinata.cloud/pinmanager?") {
        _mint(msg.sender, MILES_MORALES , 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, GWEN_STACY , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, PETER_B_PARKER , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, MIGUEL_O_HARA , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, HOBBIE_BROWN ,  1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, JESSICA_DREW , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, PAVITIR_PRABHAKAR , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, PENI_PARKER , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, PETER_NOIR_PARKER , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, PETER_PORKER , 1 , "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SPIDEY_TOKENS, 10**20, "");
       }


       function uri(uint256 _tokenId) public pure override returns(string memory){
         return string(abi.encodePacked(
           "https://app.pinata.cloud/pinmanager?",
             Strings.toString(_tokenId),
            ".json"
          )
        );
      }


      function contractURI() public pure returns(string memory) {
         return 
           "https://app.pinata.cloud/pinmanager?";
      }



}
```

---

**The test I made for my code.**

```
    const { loadFixture } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
    const { expect } = require("chai");
    import hre from "hardhat";
    import { ethers } from "hardhat";

    let spiderVerse;
    let SpiderVerse;

    describe("SpiderVerse", function () {
    before(async function (){
    SpiderVerse = await ethers.getContractFactory("SpiderVerse");
    spiderVerse = await SpiderVerse.deploy();
    await SpiderVerse.deployed();
     })
```

As you can see I barely have anything as I am just starting out. How would I even test for the constructor to mint all the tokens? It is a simple smart contracta so I would imagine I wouldnt have to test too much code and since I inherited multiple contracts from
OpenZeppelin which is a battle tested network I would assume I dont have to test al those other contracts correct? This typescript syntax looks simple but I am quite confused on naming schemes and such. Hope to hear from some of you guys! I always learn so muhc on here and get so much help. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to test the creation of all tokens:

```
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { Contract, Signer } from 'ethers';

describe('SpiderVerse Contract', function () {
  let spiderVerse: Contract;
  let owner: Signer;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    owner = deployer;

    const SpiderVerseFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('SpiderVerse');
    spiderVerse = await SpiderVerseFactory.connect(owner).deploy();
    await spiderVerse.deployed();
  });

  it('should mint all tokens to the owner in the constructor', async function () {

    const balanceMiles = await spiderVerse.balanceOf(await owner.getAddress(), 0);
    const balanceGwen = await spiderVerse.balanceOf(await owner.getAddress(), 1);
   
    expect(balanceMiles).to.equal(1);
    expect(balanceGwen).to.equal(1);
  
  });

 

});
```

If I did not understand correctly, please ask more clearly so that I can guide you

Comment: thank you so much! However when I test it I get an error saying that spiderVerse.deployed is not a function. When I tested my previous test it as throwing the same errors. What does this error even mean?

Comment: Just comment this line and test again :   // await spiderVerse.deployed();

Comment: actually it worked! Thank you so much! All this is making sense. So since I only have the constructor essentially is that all I need to test for? I am thinking about testing the uri functionalty as well

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything to test URI, the only thing that can be tested is the value of the string that is equal to the desired value.

Comment: awesome! and one more thing I have to ask. Do I have to deploy my smart contract BEFORE connecting it to my frontend application?

Comment: Yes, you need to deploy it first, now on the main network, test network or local, it depends on your application.